# How does Schwinger transform a static $(\phi,0)$ to $(\phi ', A)$ in a moving frame?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, classical-electrodynamics

Schwinger writes in his paper *Electromagnetic mass revisited*:

> Any spherically symmetrical charge distribution of total charge $e$, at rest, is represented by the potentials
>
> $$\phi \sim ef(r^2),\quad \vec A = 0 \tag{4}$$
>
> where, at sufficiently large distances,
>   $$ f(r^2)\sim (r^2)^{-1/2}\tag{5}$$
>
> The covariant description of this situation relative to any uniformly moving rest frame is [metric: -1,1,1,1]
>   $$A^{\mu}(x) = \frac{e}{c}v^{\mu}f(\zeta^2),\quad\zeta^{\mu}=x^{\mu}+\frac{1}{c}v^{\mu}(\frac{1}{c}vx)\tag{*}$$
>   where $v^2\equiv~v^{\mu}v_{\mu}=-c^2,\quad v\zeta=0$

What strategy is he using to get these covariant transformations (*)?

The obvious way to me is to use the general transformation $A'^{\nu} = \Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}A^{\mu}$, but I don't see evidence for Schwinger doing it like this.